# $y''+(5+2\cos x)y=0, y(0)=0, y'(0)=1$. Find the upper bound and lower bound of the times that $y(x)=0$ in $[0,100]$ such that $y(x)$ is the solution.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$y''+(5+2\cos x)y=0, y(0)=0, y'(0)=1$$

Find the upper bound and lower bound of the times that $y(x)=0$ when $x\in[0,100]$ such that $y(x)$ is the solution.

Since  $y$ is a continuous function, $y(0)=0, y'(0)=1$ then $\exists x_1\in [0,100]$ such that $\forall x\in [0,x_1), f(x)>0.$

That's all I have. I am really get stuck and will be grateful for help.

Thanks !

Comment: There is the Sturm-Picone comparison theorem, a solution must at least oscillate as much as the solutions to $y''+3y=0$ and at most as much as those for $y'+7y=0$. Then this equation has the form of a Matthieu equation, there exist some better statements about its solution.